# How do I tokenize a char array to different int in C?

Tags: c

I'm not familiar with `C` and I'm getting frustrated. I need to create 3 `int` variables from the `char` array token. This is supposed to be a date mm/dd/yyyy. My 3 `int` variables would be:

```
int monthNum; 
int dayNum;  
int yearNum;
```

```
void handlePrint() { 
  char token[MAX_COMMAND_TOKEN_LENGTH]; // Placeholder for the first argument
  int weekDays = 7;
  int numDays = 31;

  if (getCommandWord(token, MAX_COMMAND_TOKEN_LENGTH) != '\n') {
    printf("Too many arguments for print command! It must be in the form of print MM/DD/YYYY.\n");
    while (getCommandWord(token, MAX_COMMAND_TOKEN_LENGTH) != '\n');
    return;
  }
  printf("printing the weeks of month %s\n\n", token);
}
```

I tried to tokenize the token by doing the following:

```
char* endPoint = "/";
long int monthN = strtol (token, &endPoint, 10);
```

which gets the first variable, how can I create the two other variables?

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: `if (sscanf (token "%2d/%2d/%4d", &monthNum, &dayNum, &yearNum) != 3) { fputs ("error: invalid token format.\n", stderr); return 1; }` (**note** `token` must be a *nul-terminated* string, not just 10-characters in an array)

Comment: I'm not sure using `%2d` is appropriate, as this will not catch an error if the day is > 31 or the month is > 12.  Since there will need to be data validation after the scanf regardless, it seems wrong to use a width here as partial validation.  But it (probably) doesn't hurt.

Comment: It doesn't. You will also need to adjust for a 2-digit date as part of the validation so that `1/3/21` is also valid input.

Comment: If you're using a Posix C library, take a look at `strptime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comment above, given you are separating a date, if `token` is returned as a string from `getCommandWord(token, MAX_COMMAND_TOKEN_LENGTH) != '\n')` , then simply passing `token` to `sscanf()` is an easy way to separate the month, day and year values. You could simply do:

```c
    if (sscanf (token, "%2d/%2d/%4d", &monthNum, &dayNum, &yearNum) != 3) { 
        fputs ("error: invalid token format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

That will separate the `monthNum`, `dayNum` and `yearNum` into integer values, but you will still need to validate that `monthNum` is `1 - 12`, `dayNum` is `1 - 31` (at minimum) and then optionally handle `yearNum` as either a 1-digit, 2-digit or 4-digit value. This can largely be handled however you like; e.g. if the year is less than `21` assume the present century and add `2000`, if the year is greater than `21` an less than `100` add `1900`, etc. This is completely up to you.

A quick example that implements the logic above, after prompting the user to enter a date could be done similar to the following. `fgets()` is used for input as `getCommandWord()` is not given in your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 256        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    char input[MAXC];
    int m, d, y;
    
    fputs ("enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): ", stdout);                /* prompt */
    if (fgets (input, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {                   /* read/validate input */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 0;
    }
    if (sscanf (input, "%2d/%2d/%4d", &m, &d, &y) != 3) {       /* separate int m, d, y */
        fputs ("error: invalid input format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    /* validation of m, d, y values */
    if (m < 1 || 12 < m) {                                      /* check month 1-12 */
        fputs ("error: invalid month value.\n", stdout);
        return 1;
    }
    if (d < 1 || 31 < d) {                                      /* check day 1-31 */
        fputs ("error: invalid date value.\n", stdout);
        return 1;
    }
    /* adjust 2-digit day, 0-21 year 2000, 22-99 year 1900  */
    if (y <= 21)
        y += 2000;
    else if (y < 100)
        y += 1900;
    
    printf ("month : %d\nday   : %d\nyear  : %d\n", m, d, y);
}
```

This is just a quick example, you can, and should adjust the year handling and add any additional validations to fit your requirements.

**Example Use/Output**

Full number of digits

```
$ ./bin/split_date
enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): 12/21/1967
month : 12
day   : 21
year  : 1967
```

Single digit month/day, 2-digit year greater than 21:

```
$ ./bin/split_date
enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): 1/2/67
month : 1
day   : 2
year  : 1967
```

2-digit year less than or equal to 21:

```
$ ./bin/split_date
enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): 2/11/21
month : 2
day   : 11
year  : 2021
```

Invalid month:

```
$ ./bin/split_date
enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): 13/11/21
error: invalid month value.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped me a lot! If I need to do the same, but with 2 tokens in the same line separated by a space (mm/dd/yyyy mm/dd/yyyy)  How could I do it?                             
char token1[MAX_COMMAND_TOKEN_LENGTH]; //1st arg (from date) 
char token2[MAX_COMMAND_TOKEN_LENGTH]; //2nd arg (to date)

int month1, month2;
int day1, day2;
int year1, year2;                                                                                                                   
So it's the same situation, but now I need to print 6 different int variables because I have two dates.

Comment: You do it the EXACT same way `if (sscanf (input, "%2d/%2d/%4d %2d/%2d/%4d", &m1, &d1, &y1, &m2, &d2, &y2) != 6) {` You can also `switch()` on return and check return against `5` (you got all but last `y2`) or `4` (all but last `d2`, `y2`) and do on...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, that helped me a lot!
If I need to do the same, but with 2 tokens in the same line separated by a space (mm/dd/yyyy mm/dd/yyyy) How could I do it?

```
char token1[MAX_COMMAND_TOKEN_LENGTH]; //1st arg (from date) 
char token2[MAX_COMMAND_TOKEN_LENGTH]; //2nd arg (to date) 

int month1, month2; 
int day1, day2; 
int year1, year2;
```

So it's the same situation, but now I need to print 6 different int variables because I have two dates.